# Why does C++ constructor accept incorrect type as a parameter?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The title pretty much says it all. I have a constructor

```
Brain::Synapse::Synapse(Neuron *new_neuron);
```

But when I pass it an incorrect type (a member from a vector like this)

```
std::vector<Motor_Neuron*> neurons;
Synapse *new_synapse = new Synapse(neurons[neuron_index]);
```

It works just fine (and that's the issue). `Motor_Neuron` is a derived class from `Neuron`, so I suspect this is why. My problem ultimately is that I need some `Synapse`s to be connected to `Neuron`s and others to `Motor_Neuron`s. The `Synapse` class has a member that is a pointer to the "connected neuron". I have been trying to overload the constructor, but I don't think that will work, because if one of the constructors accepts the wrong type I don't see how the correct constructor will be selected.

Comment: You don't want to do this, as since `Motor_Neuron` is derived from `Neuron`, it's expected for that to work. That said, if you wrote deleted the constructor in the synapse, it should reject the code: `Synapse(Motor_Neuron*) = delete;` . The right way to do it is probably to have another subclass of `Neuron`, something like `Regular_Neuron`?

Comment: If the constructor accepts a `Neuron` type It should accept any `Neuron` derivated types, its the way Inheritance works. I think you should analyze the needed of a specific constructor for `Motor_Neuron` type.

Comment: @Justin Well `Neuron` is that subclass is the point. `Motor_Neuron`s just have some additional functionality. However, they aren't allowed to have synapses, and thus far to solve that I've made sure that synapses are never added, but I think some refactoring may be in order because this is a bit like the circle ellipse problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: @MatiasCerrotta I just need to be able to connect to either a `Motor_Neuron` or `Neuron` with a synapse, and that connection is a pointer, and the pointer type needs to match.

Comment: @Mr.HelloBye in order to validate that, you need to change your design. A good starting point could it be set `Neuron` like an `abstract class` and create a new derivated class called `Normal_Neuron`. Then, add two constructors for `Synapse`: `Synapse(Motor_Neuron*)` and `Synapse(Normal_Neuron*)`.

Comment: @MatiasCerrota so the point of that is to ensure that the correct constructor is selected because the two options don't have that inheritance relationship right? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Motor_Neuron` inherits from `Neuron`, then it isn't an incorrect type.  That is the entire basis of inheritance; that inherited classes *are* their parent classes, just with some extra bits and pieces.

It sounds more like you need to work on your application's class hierarchy.  The **SOLID** principles are great guidelines.  The relevant one is the **Liskov Substitution Principle** which states that “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.”  If your `Motor_Neuron` cannot fill the role of a `Neuron`, then it should not inherit from it.  If it needs to leverage some functionality from a `Neuron`, maybe have it have a `Neuron` as a member and use its functions from there.

There are work arounds with creating a `Motor_Neuron` constructor and deleting it or throwing an exception, but I don't really condone trying to fix the symptom like that, and instead get to the source; your design.

Comment: I've read about SOLID and have been trying to apply it, but I didn't understand all of it and I'm still fairly green. Thank you very much for your answer, it explained (I think) perfectly what I need to do and what I needed to know to do it.

Comment: The main takeaway I got from SOLID is what you said about fixing the design, solving the circle ellipse problem just involves defining them independently because in a programming context they're quite unrelated even though they are related in geometry. (This comment is for posterity)

Comment: Note that when you need everything from inheritance except the "derived class is-a base class" contract, you can use private inheritance.